# Set default for dropdownlist in view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have a dropdownlist that I want to set a default value for but the way I have it set up does not work with all the examples I have seen on the web.  Here is my controller code for getting the string:

```
ViewBag.RoleId = new SelectList(db.Roles, "RoleId", "RoleDescription");
```

Then here is the code of my dropdownlist in the view:

```
@Html.DropDownList("RoleId", null, "Select Role", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

I want to set that dropdownlist to be defaulted to a User Role but I cannot figure it out.

Here is the code for my roleID in my model trying to set the default value:

```
[Display(Name = "Role")]
[Required]
[DefaultValue('B2323674-45DC-45E7-91D2-E635CF63C04A')]
[ForeignKey("Role")]
public Guid RoleID { get; set; }
```

problem is I am getting an error on the Guid Default saying that it is too long for a string literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this overload of the `SelectList` that accepts default value:

```
ViewBag.RoleId = new SelectList(db.Roles, "RoleId", "RoleDescription", selectedValue);
```

Where selectedValue is an object of whatever type is in your list.

> Initializes a new instance of the SelectList class by using the
>   specified items for the list, the data value field, the data text
>   field, and a selected value.

```
public SelectList(
    IEnumerable items,
    string dataValueField,
    string dataTextField,
    object selectedValue
)
```

So in your case:

```
ViewBag.RoleId = new SelectList(db.Roles, "RoleId", "RoleDescription", "B2323674-45DC-45E7-91D2-E635CF63C04A");
```

[more info.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist.selectlist(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.SelectList.)

Also there's another solution that personally I recommand you that, Using jQuery in view for selection for example the first item of the drop down list:

```
$("#target").val($("#target option:first").val());
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `ViewBag` property and your model property are named the same. When Razor renders the values for your fields it uses the data from `ModelState`. `ModelState` is composed from values from `ViewBag`, `ViewData`, `Request` and `Model` as a last resort. In other words, since the name of the `ViewBag` property and `Model` property are the same, you're essentially saying that the selected value of `RoleId` is the entire `SelectList`, which obviously is not what you want.

The simplest solution is to simply name your `ViewBag` property something else, like `ViewBag.RoleIdChoices`. Then, you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple things going on here.

You won't be able to bind a dropDownList to a ViewBag collection "Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched." Meaning, you need to include your SelectList into your Model.

You can set a SelectedValue in your SelectList

```
ViewBag.RoleId = new SelectList(db.Roles, "RoleId", "RoleDescription", <DefaultRoleObj>);
```

You need to include the reference to you selectList in your DropDownList

```
@Html.DropDownList("RoleId", <Model.SelectList>)
```

Comment: Thank you @drooksy but how do I set a default value with that?

Comment: In my example, RoleId would be included in the Model set to the 'default'. This is done using the expression x => x.RoleId. To bind to d DropDownListFor you'll need two parts 1. a list of all the roles 2. the selected role.

Comment: Thank you droosky but it will not let me set a guid as a default value in my model.  I will place the code for my RoleID in my original question.